# Print Snowflake Query in stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use Snowflake stored procedures and would like to print the SQL statement in the stored procedure below to the screen.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE read_western_provinces()
  RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS
  $$
  var return_value = "";
  try {
      var command = "SELECT * FROM western_provinces ORDER BY province;"
      var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: command } );
      var rs = stmt.execute();
      if (rs.next())  {
          return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);
          return_value += ", " + rs.getColumnValue(2);
          }
      while (rs.next())  {
          return_value += "\n";
          return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);
          return_value += ", " + rs.getColumnValue(2);
          }
      }
  catch (err)  {
      result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
      result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
      result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
      }
  return return_value;
  $$
  ;
```

How can I print the value of command variable (which contains the SQL) to the screen whenever stored procedure is executed?

thanks

Comment: See my answer below on how to print/return the command. But what are you trying to achieve with this procedure? A stored procedure can return only a single value.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found a way to do this, but there are a few options to get close at least.

1. You can insert output into a table.
2. You can return a variant instead with debugging output in an array or similar

   ```
   return { "output":return_value, "debug":result }
   ```
3. Use a procedure to replicate something similar. See similar post from the snowflake community: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009Uu3cTSAR/debugging-procedures-technicques-print-std-out-etc)

Answer (score 3):

Use `getSqlText()` to return a statement as text, see [docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#getSqlText).

Add the return statement from below to the end of your procedure to have it print the statement when it is called.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE read_western_provinces()
  RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS
  $$
  var return_value = "";
  try {
      var command = "SELECT * FROM western_provinces ORDER BY province;"
      var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: command } );
      var rs = stmt.execute();
      if (rs.next())  {
          return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);
          return_value += ", " + rs.getColumnValue(2);
          }
      while (rs.next())  {
          return_value += "\n";
          return_value += rs.getColumnValue(1);
          return_value += ", " + rs.getColumnValue(2);
          }
      }
  catch (err)  {
      result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
      result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
      result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
      }
  return stmt.getSqlText(); -- < will print/return the statement text
  $$
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If we use:

```
return { "output":return_value, "debug":result }
```

It gives an output like:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just use call method after the procedure.

1.CALL read_western_provinces('database name','schema name');

### Syntax

CALL ('database_name','schema_name');